# Не могу понять почему выходит ошибка в коде, тема InputStream и OutputStream

Tags: java, java-output-stream

всем хорошего дня! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка в данном коде.

Выходит ошибка: выходной поток оказался пуст, когда этого не ожидалось.

Задание состоит в следующем: Напишите метод void print(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) который принимает InputStream и OutputStream, считывает все байты из inputStream и записывает в OutputStream только четные.

Пример ввода: 3, 10, 4, 5, 7

Пример вывода: 10, 4

Мой код:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{2, -11, 7, 51, 64});
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        print(stream, outputStream);

    }


    public static void print(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        byte result;
        int i;
        while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            if ((result = (byte) i) % 2 == 0) {
               outputStream.write(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При каких условиях вы получаете ошибку?

Comment: мои входные данные: {2, -11, 7, 51, 64}. Может быть проблема в этой записи? outputStream.write(result);

Comment: Я выполнил ваш код - все работает как нужно. Видимо, вы пытаетесь как то получить записанные данные. Каким образом? Прикрепите stack trace ошибки

Comment: Попробовала переписать так, но все равно выходит ошибка, но уже другая: Тест №1 провален.
print(in, out)
in: [0]
out: [0]

Comment: public static void print(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int n; (n = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1;)
        if ((byte) n % 2 == 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }

Comment: Вам не нужно ничего переписывать, в вопроссе у вас рабочее решение. Проблема не в нем. Что за тест у вас проваливается?

Comment: @instahipsta282, код загружаю на учебной платформе и она выдает ошибку без указания конкретных комментариев, только вот это: Тест №8 провален, выходной поток оказался пуст, когда этого не ожидалось

Comment: Попробуйте после выхода из цикла while вызвать метод outputStream.flush();

Comment: Попробую, спасибо)

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Резюмирую комментарии:
Проблема в том, что вы неправильно работаете с IO.

Проблема в задании с тем, что внутри `ByteArrayOutputStream` зашит буфер, который после записи необходимо "прочищать" с помощью метода `flush()`, чтобы не потерять еще не записанную информацию.

Вторая проблема в том, что вы не закрываете потоки записи и чтения, что в случае с чтением/записью из массива не ведет к каким-то губительными последствиям, но в общем случае лучше использовать конструкцию `try-with-resources`, так вы освободитье себя от необходимости самому освобождать ресурсы и делать `flush()`, все выполнится автоматически после выхода из блока `try`.

Comment: большое спасибо за подробный комментарий :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void print(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
int len = inputStream.read();
    int i =0;
    while (len != -1) {
        if (len % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(len);
            outputStream.write(len);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        len = inputStream.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]